# Filter out rows from CSV before loading to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a large csv file, that I cannot load into a DataFrame using read_csv() due to memory issues. However in the first column of the csv there is a {0,1} flag, and I only need to load the rows with a '1', which will easily be small enough to fit in a DataFrame. Is there any way to load the data with a condition, or to manipulate the csv prior to loading it (similar to grep)?

Comment: You could easily make a new csv filtered on that column, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**`pd.read_csv`s**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) the `comment` parameter and set it to `'0'`

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """col1,col2
1,a
0,b
1,c
0,d"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), comment='0')

   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     1    c
```

You can also use `chunksize` to turn `pd.read_csv` into an iterator and process it with `query` and `pd.concat`
***NOTE:*** As the OP pointed out, chunk size of `1` isn't realistic.  I used it for demonstration purposes only.  Please increase it to suit individual needs.

```
pd.concat([df.query('col1 == 1') for df in pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), chunksize=1)])
# Equivalent to and slower than... use the commented line for better performance
# pd.concat([df[df.col1 == 1] for df in pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), chunksize=1)])

   col1 col2
0     1    a
2     1    c
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what are you talking about, just as it was intended to be used :-)

Comment: I tried to generalize the problem, but in reality the filter I'm using a string in the middle of the document. The comment field answered my question exactly, but is limited in that it only works on a single character at the beginning of the file. The concat solution works perfectly, although I increased the chunksize - 1 was too slow. I also needed to add low_memory = False to get around some data_type issues.    
     mtms = pd.concat([df.query('Pool=="FX"') for df in pd.read_csv(mtms, chunksize=1000, low_memory = False)])

Comment: @ibav Yes!  Please increase the chunk size.  `1` was for demonstration purposes.